# parsing a strange file into a text file

Tags: python

I have a file like this small example:

small example:

```
>ENSG00000003249|ENST00000002501|DBNDD1|2079
GCCGCGGCCCCCCGGTTGCTGCCCCGATGCGCTGCGCCCGGAGCCGGGGCCGAGTCGCTG
CCGCAGCTGTTGGGGCGCCCGGGCCAGGCGACGCCGCCGTCGCCCGTGCCCCTCCCAGAC
CGCACCGGCCGC
>ENSG00000048028|ENST00000003302|USP28|4669
AGTCCTGAGAGGCTGGGCCGGCGGCGGCTGCGGCGGGAGACCGGTGACCCGCGGCTGGGC
GCCTCGGCC
```

the first line which is started with `">"` has 4 parts separated by `"|"` and the next line is a sequence of characters related to the line started with `">"`.
I want to parse this file into a text file in which 5 columns. the first 4 columns would be in the first line started with `">"` and the fifth line is the sequence.
for example foe the last sequence the results would be like this:

```
ENSG00000048028 ENST00000003302 USP28 4669 AGTCCTGAGAGGCTGGGCCGGCGGCGGCTGCGGCGGGAGACCGGTGACCCGCGGCTGGGCGCCTCGGCC
```

I made this code but did not work:

```
list = []
with open(inputfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            parts = line.split('|')
        else:
            parts = sequence
        list.append(parts)

infile = open('test.txt', 'w')
for item in list:
  infile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: This is the [FASTA file format](http://bioperl.org/formats/sequence_formats/FASTA_sequence_format), containing DNA information. You could use [`BioPy.SeqIO()`](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) or you could parse it manually.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to convert one text format into another. Are you trying to feed this data into another program that you didn't write?

Comment: so you want to reformat the above text into two lines of substrings separated by space?

Comment: because I want to handle the resulting file

Comment: @bzmby: and you can't handle the current format? If you can write a new file with this data, you could just handle the same data *without writing it out first*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [FASTA file format](http://bioperl.org/formats/sequence_formats/FASTA_sequence_format). If you want to manually parse this then store the header line for later use. Note that the sequence can be broken across multiple lines; write out your combined columns only when you reach the end or reach a new header.

I'd use the `csv` module to write your output:

```
import csv

with open(inputfile) as f, open('test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    header = sequence = None
    out = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='|')
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):  # header
            # write out previous data
            if header:
                entry = header + [''.join(sequence)]
                out.writerow(entry)
            header = line.strip('>\n').split('|')
            sequence = []
        else:
            sequence.append(line.strip())

    if header:
        entry = header + [''.join(sequence)]
        out.writerow(entry)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> demoinput = StringIO('''\
... >ENSG00000003249|ENST00000002501|DBNDD1|2079
... GCCGCGGCCCCCCGGTTGCTGCCCCGATGCGCTGCGCCCGGAGCCGGGGCCGAGTCGCTG
... CCGCAGCTGTTGGGGCGCCCGGGCCAGGCGACGCCGCCGTCGCCCGTGCCCCTCCCAGAC
... CGCACCGGCCGC
... >ENSG00000048028|ENST00000003302|USP28|4669
... AGTCCTGAGAGGCTGGGCCGGCGGCGGCTGCGGCGGGAGACCGGTGACCCGCGGCTGGGC
... GCCTCGGCC
... ''')
>>> outfile = StringIO()
>>> f = demoinput
>>> header = sequence = None
>>> out = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='|')
>>> for line in f:
...     if line.startswith('>'):  # header
...         # write out previous data
...         if header:
...             entry = header + [''.join(sequence)]
...             out.writerow(entry)
...         header = line.strip('>\n').split('|')
...         sequence = []
...     else:
...         sequence.append(line.strip())
...
178
>>> if header:
...     entry = header + [''.join(sequence)]
...     out.writerow(entry)
...
114
>>> print(outfile.getvalue())
ENSG00000003249|ENST00000002501|DBNDD1|2079|GCCGCGGCCCCCCGGTTGCTGCCCCGATGCGCTGCGCCCGGAGCCGGGGCCGAGTCGCTGCCGCAGCTGTTGGGGCGCCCGGGCCAGGCGACGCCGCCGTCGCCCGTGCCCCTCCCAGACCGCACCGGCCGC
ENSG00000048028|ENST00000003302|USP28|4669|AGTCCTGAGAGGCTGGGCCGGCGGCGGCTGCGGCGGGAGACCGGTGACCCGCGGCTGGGCGCCTCGGCC
```

Comment: I don't know if you have tried that or not but output is like this: ENSG00000003249|ENST00000002501|DBNDD1|2079|"GCCGCGGCCCCCCGGTTGCTGCCCCGATGCGCTGCGCCCGGAGCCGGGGCCGAGTCGCTG
"|"CCGCAGCTGTTGGGGCGCCCGGGCCAGGCGACGCCGCCGTCGCCCGTGCCCCTCCCAGAC
"|"CCGCAGCTGTTGGGGCGCCCGGGCCAGGCGACGCCGCCGTCGCCCGTGCCCCTCCCAGAC
CGCACCGGCCGC
"

Comment: @bzmby: I think the sequences need to be stripped, I suspect there are newlines in there. I've added that now.

Comment: that is nice. but still I have only one column. and separation is "|". I want to have 5 columns

Comment: @bzmby: so what separator *did* you want? You have *5* columns, separated by `|` right now. Just pick a different delimiter if you want a different one, in the `csv.writer()` definition.